# Is Libege and Liège the same?

Tags: historical-gazetteer, belgium

I came across the city name of "Libege" when doing genealogy research.

Is Libege a historical spelling of the modern-day city of Liège?

Source (among others): [Geneagraphie family tree](http://geneagraphie.com/getperson.php?personID=I476848&tree=1)

Comment: Welcome to GFH.SE! From a quick review of online sources, Libege is not another name for Liège. Please edit your question to include the context and source of your information, so we can evaluate whether the placename was mis-spelled or mis-transcribed, or whether it refers to another place altogether.

Comment: I agree -- there is not enough information to answer this question.  Please use the [edit] link under your question and add more information.  There is more information about how the site works in the [help] if you need it.

Comment: Hi, here is my source: Louis de Geer b. 17 Nov 1587 Libege, B d. 19 Jun 1652 Amsterdam, NH, NL: Geneagraphie - Families all over the world
http://geneagraphie.com/getperson.php?personID=I476848&tree=1

Comment: I'm not familiar with geneagraphie.com, so I'm struggling a bit with the format of the website. Are there any historical records associated with this family?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I can find no evidence that Libege is a real place. I think it is simply a spelling error for Liège on that family tree that has been perpetuated on several other family tree websites.

However you can be fairly certain that the author meant Liège by taking a quick look at the [Wikipedia page for the same person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_De_Geer_(1587%E2%80%931652)).

Comment: Your conclusion is very plausible. An alternative explanation, that I was thinking of, could be that it is a (old?) latinized or dutch form of the city name. Can we rule these alternatives out somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Well according to the sources to https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_De_Geer_(1587-1652)
he was indeed born in Liège.